# Google Compute Engine outgoing traffic

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, google-compute-engine, firewall

I've setup a VOIP server on one of my Google Compute instances. I've opened all tcp/udp ports, yes it's a bad idea, but at this point I'm troubleshooting, so it's okay because later I will lock it down.

However there is an issue, and I'm trying to figure out is it a Google firewall issue or a VOIP server config. The issue is that the traffic from the VOIP server to the cellphone who is calling is not being streamed.

I concluded this because I can't hear sound on my cellphone when I make a test call, I can however hear myself on the soft phone.

My question is about when I add a firewall rule `tcp:1-65535` and `udp:1-65535` and stop the iptables on my Centos 6.7 server. Does that mean that essentially all inbound/outbound communication is enabled? Is it safe to rule out the Google firewall? If the firewall is still blocking my outgoing traffic, how do I get pass that?

Comment: Since this question is not programming related it is more suited for serverfault.com, specifically: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic coming in is not the same as traffic going out.  Duh, right?  But here's the thing, if you're running on a google network ( the equivalent of an AWS::VPC ) **and** you are **not** using a proxy server ( or NAT ) then your traffic will **not** be going out like you think.

Since you're trouble shooting, you might want to give your instance an external IP and see if anything changes.  If you already have one, then you might have a different problem.  In either case you can also use tcpdump to sniff the outbound traffic to see if it's even trying to leave the instance:

tcpdump -i eth0 port VOIP_PORT

Comment: does this command `tcpdump` work for udp ports too? IF it does I can see some packets going back and forth

Answer (score 0):

If you opened all these ports and stopped the firewall you should have allowed all the traffic, but you can always double check.

In order to check inside the server if the ports are listening for traffic you can issue:

You will check all opened ports and listening ports on the server.

```
lsof -i
```

To check if there is a firewall blocking the traffic you can nmap the external IP address of your server.

```
nmap -P0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

If the ports are blocked it will mention on the output

Also you can check if your VoIP implementation needs ICMP in order to perform any initial conversation, and maybe you don't have ICMP enabled on your network.

```
tcp:icmp
```